# Get a substring starting with certain text

Tags: javascript

I have string

```
str = 'ab created > 2017-04-22 AND creator ="abc" ORDER BY reporter'
```

What I need is, I want to remove the substring that starts with ORDER..

Result:

```
str = 'ab created > 2017-04-22 AND creator ="abc"'
subString = 'ORDER BY reporter'
```

Comment: You already know the key, that is `ORDER BY` so you could just do `str.split("ORDER BY")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = 'ab created > 2017-04-22 AND creator ="abc" ORDER BY reporter'


function SliceMe(origStr,slicer){

var result =origStr.slice(0,origStr.indexOf(slicer));

var result1 =origStr.slice(origStr.indexOf(slicer));

console.log(origStr)
console.log("result: " +result)
console.log("result1 : " + result1)

}

SliceMe(str,"ORDER");
```

Comment: are you sure ??

Comment: but the above code.. check how you passing the parameter to the function

Comment: Yes thats strange. I see a proper output when I run your code. But for me result is displayed properly, but result1 is empty

Answer (score 0):

do it with [str.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [str.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), something along the lines of:

```
var str = "ab created > 2017-04-22 AND creator ='abc' ORDER BY reporter"

var order_str = str.substring(str.indexOf('ORDER') );
var new_str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('ORDER'));

console.log(order_str,'\n', new_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes, but you can do this:

```
const newStr = str.replace(/ORDER BY.+/, '')
```

Comment: But the I need the string "ORDER BY ... " also in a different variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("ORDER BY reporter"))
```

This returns `'ab created > 2017-04-22 AND creator ="abc" '`. If you need to remove the trailing space as well, do this instead:

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("ORDER BY reporter")-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var str = 'ab created > 2017-04-22 AND creator ="abc" ORDER BY reporter';
    console.log(str);
    var subString = str.substring(str.indexOf("ORDER"));
    console.log(subString);
    var str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("ORDER"));
    console.log(str);
</script>
```